# I want to add "Category" to my WP breadcrumbs

Tags: php, wordpress, breadcrumbs

I have a premium WordPress theme which has breadcrumbs by default, but it does not show Category (and Sub-Category) item when on post page: *Home > Category > Sub-Category > Post Title*

Instead it just displays like this: *Home > Post Title*

This is the function which handles breadcrumbs:

(I marked the part of the code that I think is important with this sign, to save you time: ==========>>)

```
// BREADCRUMBS
if ( ! function_exists( 'ishyoboy_get_breadcrumbs' ) ) {
    function ishyoboy_get_breadcrumbs() {

        global $ish_options, $ish_woo_id;

        $return = '';

        $return .= '<div class="ish-pb-breadcrumbs"><div><div>' . "\n";

        if ( ! is_front_page() ) {
            if ( function_exists('is_woocommerce') ) {
                if ( !is_woocommerce() && !is_woocommerce_page() ){
                    $return .= '<a class="ish-pb-breadcrumbs-home" href="';
                    $return .= home_url();
                    $return .= '">';
                    $return .= '<span>' . __( 'Home', 'ishyoboy' ) . '</span>';
                    $return .= "</a> &gt; ";
                }

            }
            else{
                $return .= '<a class="ish-pb-breadcrumbs-home" href="';
                $return .= home_url();
                $return .= '">';
                $return .= '<span>' . __( 'Home', 'ishyoboy' ) . '</span>';
                $return .= "</a> &gt; ";
            }

        }
        else {
            $return .= '<span class="ish-pb-breadcrumbs-home">';
            $return .= '<span>' . __( 'Home', 'ishyoboy' ) . '</span>';
            $return .= "</span>";
        }

        if ( !is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
            global $page;
            $return .= $page->post_title;
        }

        if ( is_archive() && 'post' == get_post_type() && ! is_category() && ( !function_exists('is_woocommerce') || !is_woocommerce() )  ) {
            $hpage = get_page( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) );
            if ( 'page' == get_option('show_on_front') && isset($hpage) && '' != $hpage ){
                $return .=  get_page_parents($hpage->ID, TRUE, ' &gt; ', FALSE );
            }
            if ( is_day() ) :
                $return .= sprintf( __( 'Daily Archives: %s', 'ishyoboy' ), '<span>' . get_the_date() . '</span>' );
            elseif ( is_month() ) :
                $return .= sprintf( __( 'Monthly Archives: %s', 'ishyoboy' ), '<span>' . get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format', 'ishyoboy' ) ) . '</span>' );
            elseif ( is_year() ) :
                $return .= sprintf( __( 'Yearly Archives: %s', 'ishyoboy' ), '<span>' . get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format', 'ishyoboy' ) ) . '</span>' );
            else :
                $return .= __( 'Archives', 'ishyoboy' );
            endif;
        }
        else if ( is_archive() && 'post' != get_post_type() && ( !function_exists('is_woocommerce') || !is_woocommerce() )  ) {

            $type = get_post_type( get_the_ID() );

            $obj = get_post_type_object( $type );
            if ( is_object( $obj ) ){
                $return .= $obj->labels->name;
            }

        }

        if ( (is_category() || is_single()) && ( ( !function_exists('is_woocommerce_page') || !function_exists('is_woocommerce' ) ) || ( !is_woocommerce() && !is_woocommerce_page() ) ) ) {

            $post_id = ish_get_the_ID();
            $post_type = get_post_type();

            switch ($post_type){
                case 'portfolio-post' :
                    $terms = get_the_terms($post_id, 'portfolio-category' );
                    $term = ( ! empty( $terms ) ) ? array_pop($terms) : '';

                    if (isset($ish_options['page_for_custom_post_type_portfolio-post']) && '-1' != $ish_options['page_for_custom_post_type_portfolio-post']){

                        $portfolio_page = get_page($ish_options['page_for_custom_post_type_portfolio-post']);
                        $separator = " &gt; ";
                        $return .= '<a href="' . get_page_link( $ish_options['page_for_custom_post_type_portfolio-post'] ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" , 'ishyoboy' ), $portfolio_page->post_title ) ) . '">'.$portfolio_page->post_title.'</a>' . $separator;
                    }

                    if ( ! empty( $term ) ){
                        $return .= get_term_parents($term->term_id, 'portfolio-category', TRUE, ' &gt; ', FALSE );
                    }
                    break;

// from here ==========>>

                case 'post' :

                    if ( is_category() ){
                        global  $cat;
                        $category = get_category($cat);
                        if ( $category->parent && ( $category->parent != $category->term_id ) ){
                            $return .= get_category_parents($category->parent, TRUE, ' &gt; ', FALSE );
                        }
                        $return .= single_cat_title('', false);
                    }
                    else{
                        $category = get_the_category();
                        if ( is_object( $category ) ){
                            $ID = $category[0]->cat_ID;
                            $return .= get_category_parents($ID, TRUE, ' &gt; ', FALSE );
                        }
                    }
                    break;

// to here ==========>>

                default :
                    $type = get_post_type( get_the_ID() );

                    $obj = get_post_type_object( $type );
                    if ( is_object( $obj ) ){
                        $return .= '<a href="' . get_post_type_archive_link( $type ) .'">' . $obj->labels->name . '</a> &gt; ';
                    }

            }
        }
        else if ( ( function_exists('is_woocommerce_page') && function_exists('is_woocommerce') ) && (is_woocommerce() || is_woocommerce_page() )){
            ob_start();
            woocommerce_breadcrumb(array(
                'delimiter'   => ' &gt; ',
                'wrap_before' => '',
                'wrap_after'  => '',
                'before'      => '',
                'after'       => '',
                'home'        => '<span class="ish-pb-breadcrumbs-home"><span>' . _x( 'Home', 'breadcrumb', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span></span>',
            ));
            $return .= ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
            ob_end_flush();
        }
        else if (is_tax()){
            if (is_tax('portfolio-category')){

                $current_term = get_queried_object();

                if ( !empty($current_term) ){
                    //var_dump($current_term);

                    if (isset($ish_options['page_for_custom_post_type_portfolio-post']) && '-1' != $ish_options['page_for_custom_post_type_portfolio-post']){

                        $portfolio_page = get_page($ish_options['page_for_custom_post_type_portfolio-post']);
                        $separator = " &gt; ";
                        $return .= '<a href="' . get_page_link( $ish_options['page_for_custom_post_type_portfolio-post'] ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" , 'ishyoboy' ), $portfolio_page->post_title ) ) . '">'.$portfolio_page->post_title.'</a>' . $separator;
                    }

                    if ($current_term->parent != 0 ){
                        $return .= get_term_parents($current_term->parent, 'portfolio-category', TRUE, ' &gt; ', FALSE );
                    }

                    $return .= $current_term->name;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (is_page()){
            global $post;

            if ($post->post_parent != 0 ){
                $return .= get_page_parents($post->post_parent, TRUE, ' &gt; ', FALSE );
            }
        }

        if (!function_exists('is_woocommerce_page') || !is_woocommerce_page()){
            if(is_single()) {$return .= get_the_title();}
            if(is_page()) {
                global $post;
                $frontpage = get_option('page_on_front');

                if ( $frontpage && $frontpage == $post->ID){
                    /*$return .= '<a class="home" href="';
                    $return .= home_url();
                    $return .= '">';
                    $return .= '<span>' . __( 'Home', 'ishyoboy' ) . '</span>';
                    $return .= "</a>";*/
                } else {
                    $return .= get_the_title();
                }
            }
            if(is_tag()){ $return .= __( 'Tag: ', 'ishyoboy' ) . single_tag_title('',FALSE); }
            if(is_404()){ $return .= __( '404 - Page not Found', 'ishyoboy' ); }
            if(is_search()){ $return .= __( 'Search', 'ishyoboy' ); }
            if(is_year()){ $return .= get_the_time('Y'); };
        }

        $return .= '</div></div></div>';

        return $return;
    }
}

if ( !function_exists('the_post_thumbnail_caption') ) {
    function the_post_thumbnail_caption(){

        $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();

        if ( ! empty( $thumb ) ){
            $thumb_object = get_post( $thumb );
            if ( ! empty( $thumb_object ) ) {
                echo '<div class="wp-caption"><p class="wp-caption-text">' . $thumb_object->post_excerpt . '</p></div>';
            }
        }

    }
}

if ( !function_exists('get_the_post_thumbnail_caption') ) {
    function get_the_post_thumbnail_caption(){

        $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();

        if ( ! empty( $thumb ) )
            return get_post( $thumb )->post_excerpt;

        return null;
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'ishyoboy_activate_fancybox_on_blog_single' ) ) {
    function ishyoboy_activate_fancybox_on_blog_single() {

        if ( is_singular() && !is_singular( 'product' ) ){
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                    var thumbnails = jQuery("a:has(img)").not(".nolightbox").filter( function() { return /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp)$/i.test(jQuery(this).attr('href')) });

                    if ( thumbnails.length > 0){
                        thumbnails.addClass( 'openfancybox-image' ).attr( 'rel', 'fancybox-post-image-<?php the_ID() ?>');
                    }
                });
            </script>
        <?php
        }

    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'ishyoboy_activate_fancybox_on_blog_single' );


if ( ! function_exists( 'ishyoboy_dummy_functions' ) ) {
    function ishyoboy_dummy_functions() {

        if ( false ) {
            posts_nav_link();
            wp_link_pages();
            $args = '';
            add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $args );
            add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $args );
        }

    }
}
```

And then I've made a change in code which generated the desired change - Category appeared in breadcrumbs: *Home > Category > Sub-Category > Post Title*

But on the Category archive page breadcrumbs look like this: *Home > Category > Category*

Live example: http://pigtelligent.com/science/

The change I've made in above-mentioned code:

```
        case 'post' :
            $terms = get_the_terms($post_id, 'category' );
            $term = ( ! empty( $terms ) ) ? array_pop($terms) : '';
            if ( ! empty( $term ) ){
                $return .= get_term_parents($term->term_id, 'category', TRUE, ' &gt; ', FALSE );
            }
```

I know that for someone smarter this should be easy, but I've spent whole day trying to figure this out, so can you please help me? :)

Answer (score 0):

Categories can get tricky fast as posts can have multiple categories, and category landing pages can access a lot of meta which can get misleading. Make sure you've reviewed the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) page on the codex and you've got a firm understanding of how WP handles taxonomy.

Use [What The File](https://wordpress.org/plugins/what-the-file/) to find out what template you're actually on as you might not be on a category page, causing `is_category()` to return false. You could be on a single (as the `if` statement wrapping the logic you pointed out is checking `is_category() || is_single()`), or you might need to add a check for [is_archive()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_archive).

My best suggestion is to figure out if you're on a category page first, then stop all that extra logic and just spit out the category's name. Not too much help, I know, but hopefully that'll point you in the right direction

Comment: You were right, I used What The File and it is indeed *is_archive()*

Now what would be your solution to "stop all that extra logic and just spit out the category's name"?

Comment: That's great. I'd start with instead of: 
`if ( (is_category() || is_single()) && ... )` 
Try: 
`if ( is_archive() ) { ... }
else if ( is_category() ) { ... }
else if ( is_single() && ... ) { }`

Answer (score 0):

```
function the_breadcrumb() {
    global $post;
    echo '<ul id="breadcrumbs">';
    if (!is_home()) {
        echo '<li><a href="';
        echo get_option('home');
        echo '">';
        echo 'Home';
        echo '</a></li><li class="separator"> / </li>';
        if (is_category() || is_single()) {
            echo '<li>';
            the_category(' </li><li class="separator"> / </li><li> ');
            if (is_single()) {
                echo '</li><li class="separator"> / </li><li>';
                the_title();
                echo '</li>';
            }
        } elseif (is_page()) {
            if($post->post_parent){
                $anc = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
                $title = get_the_title();
                foreach ( $anc as $ancestor ) {
                    $output = '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($ancestor).'" title="'.get_the_title($ancestor).'">'.get_the_title($ancestor).'</a></li> <li class="separator">/</li>';
                }
                echo $output;
                echo '<strong title="'.$title.'"> '.$title.'</strong>';
            } else {
                echo '<li><strong> '.get_the_title().'</strong></li>';
            }
        }
    }
    elseif (is_tag()) {single_tag_title();}
    elseif (is_day()) {echo"<li>Archive for "; the_time('F jS, Y'); echo'</li>';}
    elseif (is_month()) {echo"<li>Archive for "; the_time('F, Y'); echo'</li>';}
    elseif (is_year()) {echo"<li>Archive for "; the_time('Y'); echo'</li>';}
    elseif (is_author()) {echo"<li>Author Archive"; echo'</li>';}
    elseif (isset($_GET['paged']) && !empty($_GET['paged'])) {echo "<li>Blog Archives"; echo'</li>';}
    elseif (is_search()) {echo"<li>Search Results"; echo'</li>';}
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

Get using:   `<?php the_breadcrumb(); ?>`